# deploying a c++ server and expose the interface

Tags: c++, sockets, web-applications

I am new in this socket programming and web dev thing. So I am not sure how to do this.

Basically, on my local machine, i have a server and client code...

When I start server, it also exposes a webUi.

at

```
http://localhost:8088/UI
```

Now, I have deployed this code on another machine (server) whose address is

```
http://foo.bar.com
```

How should I deploy it so that I am able to access

```
http://foo.bar.com:8088/UI from my machine...
```

Also, there is my company's proxy setting??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I deploy it so that I am able to access

If your service works on port 8088, it should "just work".

The main issue would be normal connection issues.  The most likely culprit for problems would be a firewall on `foo.bar.com` which could block incoming connections to the specified port.

Comment: I thought that was 8080, not 8088? I could be wrong...

Comment: @JohnDibling You can use any port you want - the OP specified 8088 in their posting, though.

Comment: Got'cha. Thx for elaboration.

Comment: @JohnDibling It is recommended to not to use the reserved port ranges. But if you are in a well defined environment you can choose the ports the way it fits your requirements best (except the ones that are require for external communication). I e.g. have seen setups where all web dependent services where at the ports `80xx` and `90xx`